# cannot run rails server command for already created project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have got an application which was zipped and I unzipped the files and it gave me a folder with all the required structure of a rails application. But when I am going inside the directory and running the `rails server` command, its not doing anything, but showing me the list of options rails command can do. What would have been the problem?

thanks

Comment: Showing the list of options is what the rails command does when it is executed outside the context of an application (i.e., not in the application directories). For some reason in your case rails does not think you are in your application directory. Are you sure all the bits and pieces of the application are present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained by Dave Isaacs, Showing the list of options is what the rails command does when it is executed outside the context of an application (i.e., not in the application directories).

Type the full command, including the `/script` path to the CLI.

```
script/rails server
```

instead of

```
rails server
```

where `script` is the path to the `rails` command that, in a Rails 3 application, lives in the `script` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help from app folder try:

```
ruby script/rails server
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that the application you got was written with rails 2.x. In that case, you have to start it with

```
script/server
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesnt work. I also went physically inside the directory of script to run it but its not running.